# Verilog - Assigning value to a reg twice in a single always block

Tags: verilog, counter

I am working on a counter that counts the number of bits high in an input bit-stream of variable width. The code is as follows:

```
module counter(i_clk, i_arst, i_data, o_done, o_cnt);

    // ---------------------------------------- SIGNALS ---------------------------------------- //
    // Parameters   
    parameter                   OUT_WIDTH;      // Width of the output in bits
    parameter                   IN_WIDTH;       // Number of bits in an input bit stream

    // Input
    input   wire                i_clk;          // Clock
    input   wire                i_arst;         // Active high asynchronous reset
    input   wire                i_data;         // Input data

    // Outputs
    output  reg                 o_done;         // Output done bit
    output  reg[OUT_WIDTH-1:0]  o_cnt;          // WIDTH-bit output counter

    // Internal signals
    integer                     index;          // Bit index for the input
    reg[OUT_WIDTH-1:0]          r_cnt_tmp;      // Temporary counter for assignment


    // ---------------------------------------- LOGIC ---------------------------------------- //
    // Combinational logic
    always @(*) begin
        o_cnt = r_cnt_tmp;
    end


    // Sequential logic
    always @(posedge i_clk or posedge i_arst) begin

        // Reset the counter
        if(i_arst) begin
            r_cnt_tmp   <= {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            o_done      <= 1'b0;                
            index       <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            // When a new bit stream arrives
            if(index == 0) begin
                r_cnt_tmp   <= {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};       // Reset the output data
                o_done      <= 1'b0;                    // Data is now invalid because it is a new bit stream
                                                        // It only happens after a reset or a valid data output 
            end

            // If bit is set
            if(i_data == 1'b1) begin                
                r_cnt_tmp <= r_cnt_tmp + 1; // Count up
            end

            index <= index + 1;             // Increment the index

            if(index == IN_WIDTH) begin     // The input has been completely looped over
                o_done  <= 1'b1;            // Data is now valid for the output
                index   <= 0;               // Reset the index
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Once I am done with the current bit-stream, I set the o_done signal to inform that the output data is valid and I reset the variable index to start with a new bit-stream. Then at the next clock rising edge, I reset the o_done signal and the counter value andstart counting again.

The problem I have is that my counter does not always reset. Since the signal takes its value only at the end of the block, if the first bit of the bit-stream is high, then it is not reset.

I would like to reset and start counting again in the same clock cycle because I do not want more latency and I have continuous bit-streams arriving on the input.

Is there a solution to avoid this issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you **exactly** want where. you talk about `both assignments` . All assignments are in the same block.  This one: `o_cnt = r_cnt_tmp;` is redundant. If I understand what you want you 1/ need a extra copy of your bit counter to output. 2/ You need a to take into account that a bit may arrive whilst you want to restart the count. That needs a more complex if statement to cope with the extra condition of a bit arriving or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is in these statements:

```
           // When a new bit stream arrives
            if(index == 0) begin
                r_cnt_tmp   <= {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};       // Reset the output data
                o_done      <= 1'b0;                    // Data is now invalid because it is a new bit stream
                                                        // It only happens after a reset or a valid data output 
            end

            // If bit is set
            if(i_data == 1'b1) begin                
                r_cnt_tmp <= r_cnt_tmp + 1; // Count up
            end
```

Supposedly that you have `index == 0` and `i_data == 1`. Now, the *r_cnt_tmp* value will be scheduled to become `0` after the block is executed, because you use the non-blocking assignment there.

The next block will try to increment the value, but it will use an **old** value of the counter and will happily override the previously scheduled reset value. Most likely it will not be '1' or '0'.

One way to re-write it is the following. In the example the initial value of the counter will become '1' if i_data is '1' while index is 0.

```
           // When a new bit stream arrives
            if(index == 0) begin
                r_cnt_tmp   <= i_data;       // Reset the output data to '0' or '1' depending on i_data
                o_done      <= 1'b0;                    // Data is now invalid because it is a new bit stream
                                                        // It only happens after a reset or a valid data output 
            end
            else if(i_data == 1'b1) begin   // you definitely need this 'else'             
                r_cnt_tmp <= r_cnt_tmp + 1; // Count up
            end
```

Sorry, i have not tested it, in particular when i_data is 'x'.

You might need different requirements for the initial condition. So, you can write it in your own way.